# MySQL query to get average number of items group by another column

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL table:

```
+--------------+---------+---------+
| email        | itemSku | orderId |
+--------------+---------+---------+
| 1@test.com   |     abc |     1   |
| 1@test.com   |     def |     1   |
| 1@test.com   |     ghi |     1   |
| 1@test.com   |     jkl |     1   | 
| 1@test.com   |     mno |     1   |
| 1@test.com   |     pqr |     1   |
| 1@test.com   |     abc |     2   |
| 1@test.com   |     def |     2   |
| 2@test.com   |     abc |     3   |
| 2@test.com   |     def |     3   |
| 2@test.com   |     ghi |     3   |
| 2@test.com   |     abc |     4   |
| 2@test.com   |     def |     4   |
+--------------+---------+---------+
```

I want to know the average number of different itemSku per orderId for each email.

The result would be:

```
+--------------+-------------------+
| email        | avgNbItemPerOrder | 
+--------------+-------------------+
| 1@test.com   |         4         |
| 2@test.com   |        2.5        |
+--------------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` twice, as in:

```
select
  email, avg(c)
from (
  select email, orderid, count(distinct itemsku) as c 
  from t 
  group by email, orderid
) x
group by email
```